# Understanding TOTW 153 example with namespace polution

Tags: c++, namespaces

In TOTW [153](https://abseil.io/tips/153) it is claimed that using namespace in function scope can leak in the global scope, 
in other words they claim this is:

```
namespace totw {
namespace example {
namespace {

TEST(MyTest, UsesUsingDirectives) {
  using namespace ::testing;
  Sequence seq;  // ::testing::Sequence
  WallTimer timer;  // ::WallTimer

}

}  // namespace
}  // namespace example
}  // namespace totw
```

roughly equivalent to:

```
using ::testing::Expectation;
using ::testing::Sequence;
using ::testing::UnorderedElementsAre;
...
// many, many more symbols are injected into the global namespace

namespace totw {
namespace example {
namespace {

TEST(MyTest, UsesUsingDirectives) {
  Sequence seq; // ::testing::Sequence
  WallTimer timer; // ::WallTimer
  ...
}

} // namespace
} // namespace example
} // namespace totw
```

So I expected that if I do this it will compile:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
namespace totw {
namespace example {
namespace {

TEST(MyTest, UsesUsingDirectives) {
  using namespace ::testing;
  Sequence seq;  // ::testing::Sequence

}

}  // namespace
}  // namespace example
}  // namespace totw

Sequence s; //notice no testing::
```

[It does not](https://godbolt.org/z/kgczvw). So I wonder if I am wrong in replicating the example, or is the TOTW153 example misleading?

My best guess is that their example is "wrong" in a sense that what they claim is roughly equivalent is not really equivalent in a sense I would assume it is.

Comment: In my understanding this is not what they meant. The `using ::testing::Expectation` etc. are added to the global namespace _from the perspective of the `TEST` scope_. Outside of that scope there is no effect, but the problems they list are still problems (unless you know that neither the `TEST` scope contents nor the contents of any involved namespaces will _ever_ be changed). In other words, the `using` introduces potential collisions between all symbols in that `TEST` scope and the symbols in the involved namespaces. Sounds less scary but will still bite you in the long run.

Comment: Names are not leaked to the outside of the namespace, but the outside of the namespace leaks into the namespace. If you defined a `class Sequence` in global scope (before your `TEST`), compiler would silently replace `::testing::Sequence` with `::Sequence` object (which may lead to very surprising errors when editing completely unrelated code).

Comment: @MaxLanghof ⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣⇣

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Fine, fine.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thank you :P

Comment: Tnx everybody...
 but I still feel their example "translation" is confusing... anyway TIL :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I'm just always afraid of posting something subtly wrong and having it upvoted due to saying it confidently/sounding credible.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That still happens with comments, just without downvotes (and edits) to balance it out if you _were_ wrong. I'll never understand the "I'm not sure about this so I posted it in the comments section" argument: surely if you think there's a chance you're wrong, that's _when_ you want all the peer review you can get! Not to bypass it completely.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 At the same time you can hide behind "I think" and friends more in comments (removing authority from one's statements), plus they won't become a future dupe target/solidified. They are just less prominent overall. But I'll try to be braver.

Comment: @Max I believe in you; you can do it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the "transpiled" code could lead one to think that your last snippet should work. But that's not what they meant.

The using `::testing::Expectation` etc. are added to the global namespace *from the perspective of the `TEST` scope*. In other words, the transpiled code is effectively identical to the original *only within the `TEST` scope*. Outside of that scope there is no effect, but the problems they list are still problems (unless you know that neither the `TEST` scope contents nor the contents of any involved namespaces will ever be changed). In other words, the `using` introduces potential collisions between all (present *and future*) symbols in that `TEST` scope and the symbols (present *and future*) in all the involved namespaces. Sounds less scary but will still bite you in the long run.